# Dynamically loading Twitter widget using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter, widget

I'm working on a website where we want a little Twitter logo in the corner, that when clicked will show the [standard Twitter Widget](http://www.stevemid.co.uk/twitterwidget.txt) in a box that 'pops out' of the little 24x24 logo (and toggles to hide).

I managed it ok with jquery, but I realised that it is quite slow, and thought that as most people won't be clicking on this image, the widget should be dynamically loaded only if needed.

But I seem to have reached the end of my limited jquery expertise, so would appreciate some help.

My attempt so far:

```
<div id = "twittertoggle"><img src="images/Twitter_logo.png" alt="David's Twitter feed" id="twibble" /></div>
<div id = "twitterwidget">Widget to go in this DIV.</div>
<script language="javascript" > 
$('#twitterwidget').hide();  // hide the container DIV on load

$('#twibble').bind('click', function() {  // event for clicking on the twitter logo
$('#twitterwidget').toggle();   // toggle show or hide the widget container DIV
$.getScript('http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js', function() {   // attempt to load the JS for the widget 
$.getScript('twitterwidget.js');  // fail horribly.
  });
});
</script>
```

I placed the following code into the 'twitterwidget.js' file:

```
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 320,
  height: 340,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#b0b0b0',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#f7f4f7',
      color: '#474647',
      links: '#a16d99'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('TWITTERUSERNAME').start();
```

I have tried many, many different ways to get this to work (probably 2-3 hours) but I'm now thoroughly stuck, so some advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm a little stumped as how the script knows how to put the widget in your "twitterwidget" container? there is no references

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: Me too I'm afraid. If the script is there all along (ie pageload rather than dynamically loaded) then it places the widget wherever the code is called from.

Comment: Hi Abraham - I've never used jsbin or jsfiddle before. Hopefully this is ok: http://jsbin.com/uqujus/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Your demo is OK but I'm guessing the problem is that you need to pass the `#twitterwidget` container into the `TWTR` function. You'll have to read the docs as I am not familiar with the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://web.archive.org/web/20120208150540/http://od-eon.com/blogs/stefan/asynchronous-loading-twitter-widgets

(although the widget JS does load asynchronously now.)

Comment: That is a very useful article - cracked it! Thank you.